# Favoritism in Squid Game for specific player?

Tags: analysis, squid-game

For *Squid Game*, I've seen multiple theories that Il-nam was treated differently in "Red light, Green light" because he does not have a green hue in the robot's vision but I feel like I see a faint one in the playback. Was he really safe? Or is this just conjecture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There's no evidence to support whether or not Il-nam was treated differently in Red Light, Green Light**

Looking back at the scene you can see that most people are not highlighted at first:

[image]

The robot determines who moves and who does not move.  It highlights the still players as green and the moving players as red.

[image]

As you can see, Il-nam is highlighted in the second image.

So based on that alone, we can't really tell if the robot was programmed to ignore Il-nam. We really don't know if he's treated any differently than any other player in the game up until game 4 because he plays and wins each game up until then.

It is still possible that had Il-nam moved during the red light phase that the robot would have ignored him. We never see him do it, so we don't know.